# Effect of sample frequency on deconvolution

Tags: frequency, deconvolution, resampling

I am a chemical engineer so I'm not very familiar with the methods of signal processing. Nevertheless I need to apply them now on my thesis work. Most recently a question occurred to me, that is probably answered easily with a certain insight on signal processing and FFT.

Here is my problem: I am researching residence time distributions ($\text{RTD}$) on a reactor. Therefore I inject a tracer substance and measure its concentration course over time on the inlet and outlet. So I have two signals $C_{in}$ and $C_{out}$, which are related to each other by
$$C_{out} = \text{RTD} * C_{in}$$
where $*$ stands for convolution.

To calculate the desired residence time distribution of the run one has to deconvolve the signal $C_{in}$ from the $C_{out}$ signal.

To achieve that I convert the two signals into the frequency domain via FFT:
\begin{align}
&C_{out}(t) \xrightarrow{FFT} C_{OUT}(f)\\
&C_{in}(t) \xrightarrow{FFT} C_{IN}(f)
\end{align}

After that I divide $C_{OUT}$ by $C_{IN}$ since a convolution in the time domain is a multiplication in the frequency domain.
After inverse FFT of the output I get the $\text{RTD}$.

Note: Because the amount of tracer that enters the reactor is the same that exits the reactor, the integrals of $C_{in}$ and $C_{out}$ with respect to $dt$ are of same value. Therefore the integral of the $\text{RTD}$-curve with respect to $dt$ has to be $1$.

Because the corresponding time values of the measurements of $C_{in}$ and $C_{out}$ aren't uniformly spaced I resample both with the sample frequency $f_s$ to get uni-distant time steps.

---

**Now to my problem/question**: I have noticed that the area under the RTD-curve that should be always $1$ is dependent on the sample frequency by:
$$\text{area} = \frac{1}{f_s}$$
So if the sample times are $0.2\text{s}$ apart, the $\text{area} = 0.2$. If they're $2\text{s}$ apart, $\text{area} = 2$. Only with $1\text{s}$ steps I get $\text{area} = 1$. Why?

Thank you in advance for your answers. Here is also a section of my Matlab code:

```
% resampling
fs=1
[Cout, t]=resample(Cout_orig, time_orig, fs);
Cin = resample(Cin_orig, time_orig, fs);

% deconvolution
COUT=fft(Cout);
CIN=fft(Cin);
RTD=COUT/CIN;
rtd=ifft(RTD);
rtd=rtd(:,1);

% calculating area
area=trapz(t, rtd);
```

[image: Integrals of original signals (_orig), resampled signals (_resample), fft-converted & back-converted signals (_ifft) divided by each other (see legend) and Integral of RTD over sample frequency]

Comment: I'd start by verifying that the area under the original signal and resampled signal is the same when using `trapz`. If it is, there might be something going on with the FFT scaling...

Comment: As a side note, unless your input and output signals are completely noise-less, I wouldn't simply divide both FFTs to get the frequency response. With noisy measurements, you can get a better estimate using Power Spectral Densities. $H(f) = C_{yx} / P_{xx}$ where $C_{xy}$ is the Cross-Power Spectral Density and $P_{xx}$ is the Power Spectral Density (input $x$, output $y$). Matlab has functions to compute each: --continue--

Comment: --continued-- [cpsd](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/cpsd.html?searchHighlight=cpsd&s_tid=srchtitle_cpsd_1), [pwelch](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/pwelch.html?searchHighlight=pwelch&s_tid=srchtitle_pwelch_1), or even one that does the work for you: [tfestimate](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/tfestimate.html#bufqg3p)

Comment: @Jdip thank you for your comment. I checked it, they're the same as you can see from the added graph. The problem obviously occures at the division RTD=COUT/CIN.

Comment: is there any way for you to share .csv of your signals?

Answer (score 2):

> Therefore the integral of the RTD-curve with respect to dt has to be 1.

Are you sure of this?
I understand that this comes from the theory of continuous-time systems. But you have effectively converted your continous-time system into a a discrete-time one.
Based on the definition of discrete convolution

$
y[n] = \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}  x[k]h[n-k],
$

I would rather say that the *sum* of the impulse response taps $\sum_n h[n]$ has to be 1.

Also, I see two potential problems in your MATLAB code:

1. `RTD=COUT/CIN;` is wrong. If you want to perform element-wise division, you need `RTD=COUT./CIN;` (Notice the point before the division operator).
2. Why do you need `rtd=rtd(:,1);`? In the best case (if rtd is a column) it will be unnecessary. In the worst case (if rtd is a row), it will only retain the first sample of rtd.

**EDIT**

I think I got a somewhat acceptable result with your second signal set. I set the sampling interval to the average sampling interval of your irregularly spaced samples, which results in 0.3113 seconds.

```
close all;
clc; clear;

data = readmatrix("Signals2.csv");

% Read skipping the first sample
t_raw = data(2:end,1);
x_raw = data(2:end,2);
y_raw = data(2:end,3);

% Sampling frequency
downsamplingFctr = 1;
Ts = mean(diff(t_raw))*downsamplingFctr; % seconds;
fs = 1/Ts;

[x,t] = resample(x_raw,t_raw,fs);
y = resample(y_raw,t_raw,fs);

% Normalize output
y = y/sum(y)*sum(x);

figure; 
plot(t,x);
hold on;
plot(t,y);
xlabel('time [s]');

X = fft(x);
Y = fft(y);
H = Y./X;
h = ifft(H);

% Define discrete frequency axis
f_axis = [-length(X)/2:length(X)/2-1]/length(X)*fs;

figure; 
plot(f_axis,fftshift(abs(X)));
hold on;
plot(f_axis,fftshift(abs(Y)));
plot(f_axis,fftshift(abs(H)));
xlabel('frequency [Hz]');
ylabel('Magnitude');
legend('Input','Output','Estimated transfer function')

figure; 
plot(real(h));
hold on;
xlabel('n')
ylabel('Impulse response h[n]');
```

[image]

In the case of the first signal set, things are trickier because the duration of the recoded signal is much longer. If you use the same approach as above, the bandwidth of the input signal becomes much smaller than the sampling frequency, which results in a terribly noisy estimate. Therefore I played around with downsampling factor `downsamplingFctr`. If you set values > 100 you start seeing a sensible impulse response, but you still have a significant amount of noise.

Note that downsampling implies low-pass filtering of the signals. Therefore, you can't just increment the downsampling factor indefinitely, because you would end up with significant distortion of the input signal and the result would be incorrect, even if it "looks smoother".

All in all, system identification through simple FFT division has its drawbacks and is in general deprecated as far as I know (there are specific and motivated exceptions). You will probably get better results with other techniques (Wiener filtering might be a good keyword).

Comment: Ha, good catch on the division.

Comment: Hi Vito, all the values, also the original data are descrete values. So if I speak about integration I of course mean discrete Integration/summation. But to calculate the area under the RTD-curve you have to consider the values of the time steps dt or delta t also.

Comment: I'm not sure if I need an element-wise divison or if the devonvolution is performed element-wise. The resulting RTD looks better without the element-wise division.

Comment: If I performe the divison COUT/CIN this results in a n by n matrix for RTD, where n equals the length of the vectors COUT or CIN. In the first column of the RTD-matrix I find the desired values. The other columns are all zero. Therefore rtd=rtd(:,1).

Comment: Discrete integration $\neq$ summation
The former is an approximation of an analytical integration, taking into account the discretization step, e.g. using `trapz`.
The latter is a raw sum of samples.

Comment: Regarding the division, this is what I was fearing. You are probably dividing a column by a row, not sure how MATLAB interprets that. Maybe you end up "by chance" with a correct result by retaining the first column. But you definitely need an element-wise division.

Answer (score 1):

I postet the question as a guest and proceeded with creating an account with the same email address after that, but unfortunately it didn't connect this account with the guest account. So I'm not able to comment or edit for the moment.

**This is a response to @Vitos comment on the elementwise division under answer 1.**

If you divide a vector by another vector in matlab (`A/B`, not element-wise), it solves a system of linear equations for $x$ to satisfy $A= xB$. (see documentation for the matlab function `mrdivide`).

When using this operation somehow my results turn out good and make sense. But when I use the element-wise division `A./B` they don't make sense.

**And this is a response to @Vitos comment on the summation**

You are right the sum of the deconvolved impulse response $RTD$ (`sum(rtd)`) is always 1, independent on the sample frequency $f_s$. And if you integrate it with resp. to the time steps determined by $f_s$ it takes up the value of $1/f_s$.

So the deconvolution in the frequency domain `COUT/CIN` obviously does not account for the time step information. Yet this information is relevant.

If I conduct a conventional deconvolution by solving a system of linear equations I'd also consider the time steps and the resulting rtd would have the unit [1/s].

(For example the first equation of an nummerical convolution would be
$$ C_{out}[1]=C_{in}[1] RTD[1] \Delta t $$

and the solution for $RTD[1]$ would be

$$ RTD[1]=\frac{C_{out}[1]}{C_{in}[1]\Delta t} $$

$[RTD] = 1/s$ )

So is there a 'mathematical correct' way to include the time step size information in the deconvolution via `COUT/CIN`?

Here are two examples of the original signals.

Signals1 with a long period
https://ufile.io/139k2r58

Signals2 with a short period
https://ufile.io/dctxdkzh

For each file the first column is the time vector `time_orig`, the second column is the input `Cin_orig`, and the third column is the output `Cout_orig`.

Please note that due to the process of measurement the area under `Cin_orig` isn't equal to `Cout_orig`. So you first have to normalize one signal with the other.

**EDIT**

OK, I tried it with `cpsd` `pwelch` and `tfestimate` but the results were just zero. I also tried applying a Wiener deconvolution by calculating the transfer function $G(f)$ with $$ \frac{1}{G(f)}=\frac{COUT(f)}{CIN(f)}$$
and then backcalculating the impulse response $H(f)=RTD(f)$ by solving the problem $$ 0=H(f)\biggl(1+\frac{1}{|H(f)|^2SNR}\biggr)-\frac{1}{G(f)}$$
but that gave me worse results than simply using $RTD(f)=\frac{COUT(f)}{CIN(f)}$. So I'll stick to the later approach. I think I can live with the noisy results, if necessary I can smoothen them artificially.

**To summarize your answers for my original question:**
By transforming the signals into the frequency domain and performing a deconvolution, the time step information becomes irrelevant. So the reverse transformed impulse response will give us $h(n)$ with $n$ as an integer control variable. Due to the algorythm the values of $h(n)$ will be scaled that $\sum h(n)=1$ is always valid. For a sample frequency of 1/s this wont make any difference but for a sample frequency of 4/s we have 4 times the ammount of the original values, the original values therefore are scaled down by 4. So to get the time-continous impulse response function $h(t)$ I have to rescale it with the sample frequency: $h(t)=h(n)f_s$. And thereby its physical unit $[1/s]$ also will be restored.

Maybe you guys can confirm this information.

Comment: Now I'm confused. `sum(rtd)` should not always be 1 regardless of the sampling rate, since you're discarding/adding samples by downsampling/interpolating. Unless you're normalizing by `length(rtd)`. As far as the element-wise division, Vito is **correct**: that's how you should be doing that operation.

Comment: I don't think he is changing the sample rate.

Comment: "When using this operation **somehow** my results turn out good and make sense": if you're not sure why you're getting the result you want, there's a problem. Maybe you're getting something that seem to make sense visually, but that is coming from faulty operations, and tricking you into thinking you have the correct result. Try the method I mentioned in an earlier comment on your OP and see what you get for comparison purposes. Again, matrix division in the frequency domain **does not** make sense for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: You *could* perform deconvolution by matrix inversion, but that would be in time domain. If you do it in frequency domain, it has to be an element-wise division. If the result of that operation does not make sense, there is another problem somewhere.
What are the dimensions of Cin and Cout?

Comment: "I don't think he is changing the sample rate": well now I'm REALLY confused. I thought the whole question was about resampling the data and wondering why the resulting integral has different values for different sampling rates...

Comment: "for different sampling rates" 
He is trying to "emulate" different sampling rates trough the resample function, but the same rate is used for the input and the output of the linear system. There is no resampling involved.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the question then. But regardless of the original sampling rate, if a signal $x$ at frequency $f_s$ gives $\sum{x} = K$, then resampling $x$ at frequency $Nf_s$ will roughly result in $\sum{x} = NK$. So emulating different sampling rates should give you different values when you sum the resulting signals. My main worry is the division step though, that's the main point!

Comment: Also, $\sum{\frac{x_1}{x_2}} \neq \sum{\frac{\text{resample}(x_1)}{\text{resample}(x_2)}}$

Comment: I changed to element-wise division but the `sum(rtd)` is still always 1. I have also noticed that the results become better, the smaller the resampling frequency is. So if the time steps are 20 min apart I get a expected curve with noise. If they are 0.2 seconds apart I'm just getting noise. Is there something like oversampling? (20 min apart would be absolutly not sufficient for the time step size)

Comment: That's difficult to answer without a knowledge of the matter. If your sampling frequency is too low, you might be violating Nyquist's theorem. If it is too high, you might be picking too much noise.

Comment: @Pascal "the first equation of an nummerical convolution" What you define as a "numerical convolution" is a discretized version of a continuous-time convolution integral. A proper [discrete-time convolution](https://pages.jh.edu/signals/discreteconv2/index.html) doesn't have the term $\Delta t$. In fact, a continuous impulse response has units of 1/s as you correctly say, but a discrete impulse response has no physical units.

Comment: @Jdip I attached some .csv files of the original data on my answer

Comment: @Pascal Oh, I see that your samples are irregularly spaced. Now I understand the need for the resample function.

Comment: @Pascal What is the time unit of your data? It is correct that the first sample spans more than 2500 seconds and the second one less than 140 seconds?

Comment: @Vito yes time is in seconds

Comment: @Pascal I updated my answer with an analysis of your data.

Comment: @Vito thank you for your update.  I tried your suggestions (see edit on my post)